# HttpURLConnection response missing Status Line (ProtocolException)

Tags: android, http, iis, httpurlconnection

I currently am trying to make a request (With `HttpURLConnection`) to an IIS server that will bounce me with redirects until the target destination.

The issue : `java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>`

This happens when `urlConnection.getInputStream()` is called (or `urlConnection.getResponseCode()`, which calls it).

I have seen numerous cases where the issue is simply a misconfigured server, but in this case, making a request from Chrome while faking an Android user agent yields the expected result.

Furthermore, the server is an ancient one, that has never been the source of problem, and is configured in the same way as one used in a production environnement.

Reaching another redirecting webpage works fine (Tested with `https://com.google/`, 2 redirections), and reaching a non-redirecting webpage on the server poses no problem.

I have been looking for two days, and have made no progress. ANY help would be appreciated.

---

The code that is currently used :

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = null;

try {

    URL url = new URL(urlStrings[0]);

    urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    LogHelper.Log(getBaseContext(), "Request on URL :\n\"" + url + "\"");

    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","*/*");

    urlConnection.setDoOutput(false);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

    urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);

    CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
    cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
    CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);

    urlConnection.connect();

    int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
    LogHelper.Log(getBaseContext(), "Status code is \"" + status + "\"");
    if (!url.equals(urlConnection.getURL())) {
        LogHelper.Log(getBaseContext(), "URL after redirection is :\n\"" + urlConnection.getURL() + "\"");
    }

    switch (status/100) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:

            InputStream stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            reader.close();
            break;

        case 4:
        case 5:

            InputStream errorStream = urlConnection.getErrorStream();
            BufferedReader errorReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorStream));
            String errorLine;
            while ((errorLine = errorReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(errorLine).append("\n");
            }
            errorReader.close();

            throw new Exception(builder.toString());

        default:
            throw new Exception("Unknown status code: " + status);
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    LogHelper.Log(getBaseContext(), e);
} finally {
    if (urlConnection != null) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}

return builder.toString();
```

The resulting error :

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: <html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StatusLine.parse(StatusLine.java:54)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:239)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:104)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:1120)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:951)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:482)
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(
    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(
    at com.pushmanager.clientmdm.activities.RegistrationView$1$2.doInBackground(
    at com.pushmanager.clientmdm.activities.RegistrationView$1$2.doInBackground(
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Comment: My only idea is that the server sends incorrect HTTP headers. It would be very helpful to capture TCP network stream, and provide it here. You will need to root your device for that, then use either http://www.androidtcpdump.com/ or some app like Shark for Root. You will also need to change your https:// url to http://

Comment: @pelya, The thing, is that the headers are correct when requesting from Chrome on the same device. No other way of contacting the server yields an error.
Also, the server is fixed in https, so capturing the traffic by switching to http is not possible (unfortunately). Is there any other way to get the headers?

Comment: Chrome does not use HttpURLConnection, so your request will have different HTTP headers, the server most probably replies differently. If you cannot capture logs, you can try to replace HttpURLConnection with legacy Apache HttpClient in your code, and hope that the bug goes away. You will also need to add `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` to your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this behavior was caused because of a `\n` character in the URL string.

I have no idea how okhttp managed this result, but with the character removed, the problem disappeared.